# How to use a toggle button with a callback (in an class) in PyViz?

Tags: python, widget, pyviz

I am using PyViz / Panel in a notebook. Now I want to use a toggle button inside a class, and bind a callback to it.

This code - outside a class -  is working:

```py
import panel as pn
import panel.widgets as pnw
pn.extension()

toggle = pn.widgets.Toggle(name='Toggle')

def callback(*events):
    if toggle.active is True: toggle.name = 'Active'
    else: toggle.name = 'Toggle'

watcher = toggle.param.watch(callback, 'active')
toggle.param.set_param(active=False)
toggle.param.trigger('active')

pn.Row(toggle)
```

It produces a toggle button, and when clicked, the text changes.

No I tried to put everything inside a class definition:

```py
class ToggleInClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.toggle = pn.widgets.Toggle(name='Toggle')
        self.watcher = self.toggle.param.watch(callback, 'active')
        self.toggle.param.set_param(active=False)
        self.toggle.param.trigger('active')

    def callback(self, *events):
        if toggle.active is True: toggle.name = 'Active'
        else: toggle.name = 'Toggle'

toggle_in_class = ToggleInClass()
pn.Row(toggle_in_class.toggle)
```

Again a button is produced, but this time the callback does not seem to work: The text never changes.

The watcher seems to be ok:
`toggle_in_class.watcher` gives `Watcher(inst=Toggle(), cls=<class 'panel.widgets.Toggle'>, fn=<function callback at 0x000001EC8419E510>, mode='args', onlychanged=True, parameter_names=('active',))`.

The output of `toggle_in_class.toggle.active` alternates according the toggle state.

What is wrong with my callback / class definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After correcting some stupid typos this code is working for me:

```py
class ToggleInClass():

    def __init__(self):
        self.toggle = pn.widgets.Toggle(name='Toggle')
        self.watcher = self.toggle.param.watch(self.callback, 'active')
        self.toggle.param.set_param(active=False)

    def callback(self, *events):
        if self.toggle.active is True: self.toggle.name = 'Active'
        else: self.toggle.name = 'Toggle'

toggle_in_class = ToggleInClass()
pn.Row(toggle_in_class.toggle)
```